# Feed parsing, splitting string

Tags: php, sql, xml

Say I have the following:

```
$cars = "auto1,auto2,auto3,auto4";
```

If I parse `$cars` to insert the value in my database, I get a string like "auto1,auto2,auto3,auto4".

I want to split this string when I parse the feed into "auto1, auto2, auto3, auto4" - basically add spaces between words. How can i do it?

Here's how I get values for `$cars`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach( $xml->feedinfo as $feedinfo )
{
    $cars = $feedinfo->cars;
    [...]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you just want to insert spaces into your string, why not simply replace each `,` with `, ` (comma+space)?

Comment: Why are you using a `foreach` to assign values to `$cars`? Won't that variable get overwritten every time? Why not just get the correct `$feedinfo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to add spaces:

```
$cars = str_replace(',', ', ', $cars);
```

But you could also split it into an array of elements:

```
$cars = explode(',', $cars)
```